# Update Strategy T/F before Joiner T/F

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

1) Why Update strategy Transformation can not be used before Joiner Transformation in Informatica ? 
2) why sequence generator can not be used before Joiner ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why joiner is not used after Sequence generator or Update statergy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30197877/why-joiner-is-not-used-after-sequence-generator-or-update-statergy)

Comment: Am guessing this is an interview question

Answer (score 1):

Since I hate the whole concept of 'interview questions' I'll choose to answer the second one since it IS an opportunity to explain what a joiner trans does in the first place.

A joiner trans works by reading all the rows from the 'master' side into a btree index structure, and when that is finished, the engine reads each row from the 'detail' side and attempt to match it to as many rows in the btree as possible until the last row has been read. This is true even with sorted input, but will work in 'bursts' for each group of sorted data. It is true as well for a 'full' join, but at the end, all rows of unmatched data from the master side will be send to the 'output'...

Since a sequence generator potentially outputs an infinite number of new values, the master or detail side would never be able to 'finish reading', and thus it does not make sense.